# Issues scaffolding loopback app

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am attempting to scaffold a loopbackJS app but I keep receiving the following error when I attempt to run "slc loopback":

```
-bash: slc: command not found
```

I've searched for tutorials and troubleshooting methods but nothing has worked for me thus far. I even tried reinstalling node and NPM with no luck.

It's very confusing that I'm getting this error because I ran

```
npm ls -g --depth=0
```

With these results (including the strongloop module):

```
/Users/USERNAME/.npm-packages/lib
├── bower@1.7.9
├── generator-angular-fullstack@4.0.1
├── generator-keystone@0.4.2
├── generator-keystonejs-builder@0.0.5
├── generator-loopback@1.24.1
├── generator-wordpress@2.0.2
├── grunt-cli@1.2.0
├── gulp@3.9.1
├── gulp-cli@1.2.2
├── johnny-five@0.9.61
├── mean-cli@0.12.10
├── nodemon@1.9.2
├── particle-cli@1.15.0
├── particle-io@0.12.0
├── strongloop@6.0.2
├── webpack@1.13.1
├── webpack-dev-server@1.14.1
└── yo@1.8.4
```

Lastly, I've also tried resetting my $PATH and still no luck. If anyone has any suggestions I would really appreciate the help as this is my first time using loopback.

Thanks

**Update**

From the comment provided below, I researched my $PATH and found that I didn't have node and npm inside of it.

I performed changes to the path using the following commands:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/node
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/npm
```

Resulting in my $PATH showing:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin/node:/usr/local/bin/npm
```

But I still can't get the "slc loopback" command to perform. What might I be still missing?

Comment: This really look like a $PATH issue, can you post it?

Comment: My current path is: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin

Comment: Can you check if `/Users/USERNAME/.npm-packages/bin` exists? If yes, does it contains `slc`?

Comment: And you should not have done what you did in your update, that's not how $PATH works. If you have `/usr/local/bin` then all binaries inside `/usr/local/bin` will be found.

Comment: Hey Thanks, I do not see .npm-packages. Instead I found node-modules

Comment: Are you sure? Because the output of `npm ls` in your question says otherwise...

Comment: Also check [this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md)

Comment: Yes sir, this is true. What I mean is that when I try and look for it using the the Finder I don't see it but rather I see node-modules. If I search for it by type the directory I am able to find it. When I typed in the dir, I didn't find any loopback binaries in the bin folder

Comment: Do you use sudo with npm? This is generally considered as a bad practice, I'd suggest you follow the guide I linked and reinstall loopback without sudo. [This script should do everything for you automatically](https://github.com/glenpike/npm-g_nosudo)

Comment: As it turns out, I had came across this sometime ago and stopped using sudo a few months back. This is why I'm confused as to why the command isn't running.

Comment: I don't know then. What you could do is a symlink in `/Users/USERNAME/.npm-packages/bin` to `/Users/USERNAME/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/strongloop/bin/slc.js` that should exist. The symlink should have been created by npm install...

Comment: I used the script you suggested and reset my path, still getting the error. I'll try researching the use of symlink and see if that fixes the issue.